# How to quote this raw command in Ansible YAML?

Tags: string, powershell, yaml, quoting

I am using Ansible to manage the configurations of a bunch of Windows clients. For the record, Ansible playbooks (i.e. recipes) are written in YAML.

I need to run this command on every client, and I could test it successfully in a Powershell prompt on a client machine:

```
> CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"'
```

(note the single quotes, required because of the double quotes around the filename)

Now I "just" need to write a YAML playbook and use the raw module from Ansible to send this command to a remote Powershell session. And this is where I am stuck. My command contains `:`, `'` and `"` symbols so I have no idea how to quote it properly.

I have tried a million variations, with no success so far:

```
CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"'
"CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\\Temp\\intlsettings.xml"'"
"CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:\"C:\\Temp\\intlsettings.xml\"'"
"CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f\:\"C\:\\Temp\\intlsettings.xml\"'"
```

For information, the final playbook will look something like:

```
---
- name: Configure keyboard mappings
  hosts: windows

  tasks:
  - name: apply keyboard mappings config
    raw: CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute this powershell command

```
CMD /C 'control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"'
```

powershell creates this [CommandLine](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/):

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C "control intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml""
```

Note, that no `'` are used in the CommandLine.

However, you don't need to go through cmd as no cmd functionality is used in your command.

```
control.exe intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"
```

should be enough.

I don't know ansible, but if I understand the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html) correctly, all text after `raw` is sent as a command via ssh. This means, it is interpreded by some shell. If this shell is cmd.exe, this should work:

```
tasks:
  - name: apply keyboard mappings config
    raw: control.exe intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"
```

If the shell is powershell (v3 and above (default for win8 and above, installable for win7)), this should work:

```
tasks:
  - name: apply keyboard mappings config
    raw: control.exe --% intl.cpl,, /f:"C:\Temp\intlsettings.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this when I get the opportunity. All the examples I could get my hands on use PowerShell as the default shell. It makes sense as I had to configure PowerShell on the Windows clients so it accepts commands sent from Ansible. That is probably why CMD /C is required, to call the CMD shell from PowerShell. Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Comment: If the shell is actually powershell and if I understood the ansible documentation correctly, your original command should work. I added another code snippet, that should also work. If both don't work, I probably misunderstood the ansible documentation.